# How to translate one line in front-end

Tags: magento-2.1, register

I turned on the linear translator in magento 2.

While he tries to translate the buttons "Log in" and "Register" via translate magento I can translate only "Log in" - is not possible translate "Register" button because these buttons have the same link.

In what other way can I translate the button in files "Register"?

Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in Magento Register link is called "**Create an Account**". So some one has changed its name from "**Create an Account**" to "**Register**" using "**Magento_Customer**" module's XML file.

So to translate this word, you have to add "**Register**" word and its translation into `theme/i18n/pl_PL.csv` (whatever is your language pack).

```
static:content:deploy
cache:flush
```

hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Abhishek, all works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to know that its working fine.